# How can I make React's DateTimePicker save data to a database in Wordpress?

Tags: reactjs, database, wordpress, datetimepicker

I am trying to build a block in Wordpress that has a DateTimePicker in the sidebar. The only problem is, since it is a React component and not something built into Wordpress, the data that is input into the DateTimePicker is not saved into the database. How would I go about fixing this?

Thank you!

block.json

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schemas.wp.org/trunk/block.json",
    "apiVersion": 2,
    "name": "countdown-display/countdown-display",
    "title": "Countdown Display",
    "category": "widgets",
    "description": "Shows the user a countdown from the current date and time to the date and time input in the block. If the date has passed, the countdown will no longer appear.",
    "version": "1.0",
    "textdomain": "countdown-display",
    "attributes": {
        "dateAndTime": {
            "type": "object"
        },
        "selected12Hour": {
            "type": "boolean",
            "default": true
        },
        "frontendHeading": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "editorScript": "file:./index.js",
    "style": "file:./index.css"
}
```

index.js

```
import { registerBlockType } from "@wordpress/blocks";
import {
  ToggleControl,
  DateTimePicker,
  PanelBody,
  ColorPalette,
} from "@wordpress/components";
import {
  useBlockProps,
  RichText,
  InspectorControls,
} from "@wordpress/block-editor";
import { __ } from "@wordpress/i18n";
import "./main.css";
import icon from "./icon.js";

const editorOnlyHelp =
  "This setting affects editor display ONLY. It does not affect the user's view on the front end.";

registerBlockType("countdown-display/countdown-display", {
  icon: {
    src: icon.hourglass,
  },
  edit({ attributes, setAttributes }) {
    const { dateAndTime, selected12Hour, frontendHeading } = attributes;
    const blockProps = useBlockProps();

    return (
      <>
        <InspectorControls>
          <PanelBody title={__("12 Hour or 24 Hour Clock")}>
            <ToggleControl
              label={
                selected12Hour
                  ? __("12 Hour Clock", "countdown-display")
                  : __("24 Hour Clock", "countdown-display")
              }
              help={__(editorOnlyHelp, "countdown-display")}
              checked={selected12Hour}
              value={selected12Hour}
              onChange={(newVal) => setAttributes({ selected12Hour: newVal })}
            />
          </PanelBody>

          <PanelBody title={__("Calendar", "countdown-display")}>
            <DateTimePicker
              currentDate={dateAndTime}
              // value={ dateAndTime }
              onChange={(newDate) => setAttributes({ dateAndTime: newDate })}
              is12Hour={selected12Hour}
            />
          </PanelBody>
        </InspectorControls>

        <div {...blockProps}>
          <RichText
            value={frontendHeading}
            tagName="h3"
            placeholder={__(
              "Heading for display (shown to users on frontend)",
              "countdown-display"
            )}
            onChange={(newHeading) =>
              setAttributes({ frontendHeading: newHeading })
            }
            allowedFormats={["core/bold", "core/italic", "core/link"]}
          />
          {dateAndTime == null ? (
            <h5>{__("Countdown display is not set.", "countdown-display")}</h5>
          ) : (
            <h5>
              {__(
                "Display is set to countdown to " + dateAndTime + ".",
                "countdown-display"
              )}
            </h5>
          )}
          <h5>
            {__(
              "Countdown will not display on the frontend if the inputted date has already passed.",
              "countdown-display"
            )}
          </h5>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  },
});
```